# grails constraint for service callback - property need capital first letter

Tags: grails

I've upgraded a grails project 1.3.9 -> 2.2 and now i get an error regarding the constraints of a callback to an external service having a capitalised first letter. I've removed the constraint requirement for this property, but would like to find a way to keep the constraint functionality but i need to have a property with a capital letter. I do not control the external API that is sending a capitalised param back.

The callback closure looks like this:

```
class CallbackCommand{                                                                                                                                                       
   String token                                                                                                                                                                    
   String ID                                                                                                                                                                  

   static constraints = {                                                                                                                                                          
      token nullable: false                                                                                                                                                        
      //ID nullable: false                                                                                                                                                    
   }                                                                                                                                                                               
}
```

I've commented the ID constraint as this fails due to the capitalised first letter. 
How can i enforce this constraint but keep the parameter naming consistent with the external API?

Comment: Can you post the code of your callback? This is associated with a command / domain class?

Comment: sure, question has now been amended